# Why don't these sentences use the same tense?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

> It turned out that what happened was different from what I **had expected** in my mind.

> The resultant situation is something that happened later in time than when you **made** predictions about the same.

I don't really understand why in the first sentence past perfect is used and in the second past simple. For me both actions the expectations (first sentence) the predictions (second one) came first.

May be the explanation lies in the fact that the first one  is past and the second one is  present. What is confusing me is "happened" past simple: the predictions came before the happening. So if happened is past simple what came first should be past perfect. That is why I think **had made** might be better.

This is really confusing!!!!!

Comment: In the first, I was expecting something and the expectation **preceded** what happened/ This would be the exact same thing in French. ce qui c'est passé était différent de ce que **j'avais imaginé**.

Comment: but in the second sentence   the predictions were made also before the situation  turned out differently. So in both examples predictions and expectation came first BUT apparently (because of the answer given) the second does not need past perfect as the order of events is clear enough

Comment: The second sentence, apart from the verbs is terrible English. Anyway, just like French, nothing stops you using simple past in two different clauses.

Comment: yes I know you can use simple past in two different clauses but to make clear the order of events I thought past perfect would have  been  better in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what you may have been taught, the past perfect is *not* about the order that events happened.

It is a *choice* that a speaker or writer makes, to set or maintain a "temporal viewpoint" - to look back on events from some later time.

English speakers often do not bother to use it when that temporal relationship is made clear in some other way.

So in your first sentence, "had expected" indicates that *looking back from the time when the speaker had that realisation*, their earlier expectations were different. They could have chosen a simple past, in which case there would be no particular temporal viewpoint. (This might have been ambiguous, as it would leave open the possibility that they still had these expectations later).

In the second sentence, "had made" would have been perfectly good; but since the temporal relations are clear, most English speakers would not bother to use it, and would say "made".

Comment: "Gerry's first experience with a groupie turned out somehow different from what he had in mind " Is it the same with this sentence, are the relations in this sentence clear enough that the second verb doesn't need past perfect or is it because even if the situation turned out differently he had still the same idea that he had from the beginning

Comment: One concludes that when he had the experience he stopped having the different something in mind, and so, yes there is no practical ambiguity.

Comment: @Lambie: I presume there is an error in your examples? Perhaps there was supposed to be _had_ in the second example? If so, then I disagree: same reality, different viewpoint. Or maybe I've misunderstood your intent

Comment: Colin, it is about meaning and is about the order of events the speaker wishes to express. I entered the room after he arrived. AND I entered the room after he had arrived. imply different realities. [Yes, thanks. I have corrected the omission.]

Comment: @Lambie, I can't see an objective difference.

Comment: so what are for you the different realities for me in both situation first he arrived then I entered

Comment: @YvesLefol The grammar in that sentence of yours (in your comment here) is off. Therefore, I have no idea what you even mean....And so is the grammar in your second posted sentence.

Comment: Sorry  but what sentence are you talking about Gerry? if so  I found this sentence  in an english or american comic book: I did not imagine it and because I found it unclear I thought past perfect would have been better

Comment: @YvesLefol I have been very clear and my name is NOT Gerry.

Comment: I know your name is not Gerry , Gerry is the beginning of  the example I gave ( je ne me serais pas permis de vous appeler par votre prénom)